# jQuery "Each" function for values

Tags: jquery

**EDIT:**

So, I have following ajax result:

```
function(data){
    var my_title= data.title; // values: post1,post2,post3      
    var my_name = data.name;  // values: steve,mike,sean

     var my_html ='<div class="'+ my_title +'">'+ my_name +'</div>' 
     jQuery('.my_class').append(my_html);           
};
```

So, I have two variables (`my_titles` and `my_name`) each with 3 values (`n` number values).

Then, I want to use these individual values for `my_html` variable and append them in the `.my_class`.

The result will be as follow:

```
 <div class="my_class">
    <div class="post1">Steve</div>
    <div class="post2">mike</div>
    <div class="post3">sean</div>
 </div>
```

Any suggestions to how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what is in the `my_title` variable (what kind of data structure it is).  And, describe what exactly you want to do with those   values.  "run the html function" is not a complete description of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is `my_title` a comma separated string or an array?

Comment: I made the post more clear with what I am trying to achieve. Please let me know if it is not clear. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in your code.

Even if you itereate through the array , you're setting the value again and again to all `.my_class` elements

I *assume* you're after this :

```
$.each(data.title,function (i,n){

  jQuery('#my_class').append(n.title);    //or n , we don't know the  structure

})
```

Or if you have multiple .my_class elements  and you want to add data respectively : you can do this

```
   $.each(data.title,function (i,n){

      jQuery('.my_class').eq(i).html(n.title);    //or n , we don't know the  structure

    })
```

Comment: That's exactly it! =) Thank you. I will give it a try!

Comment: Hi. I updated my post with what I am trying to achieve. Could you take a look at it for me? thanks!

Comment: Thank you! =) Learned something new today! =) Appreciate it~